# ISNULL with CONVERT

Tags: sql-server

so I have a `LEFT JOIN` query, some fields will return `NULL` (type is DateTime) If there is no equivalent in the other table. I want to replace the NULL to 'X-text'

I have tried using ISNULL but I'm receiving an error

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ISNULL(column_name,'X-test'), 110) AS [MM-DD-YYYY]
```

The error is:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I have tried to put ISNULL outside CONVERT but I started receiving an error about ISNULL needing 2 arguments (which It has).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you expect to convert 'X-test' to a datetime? Problem is there. You should instead do that after conversion to varchar:

```
select
ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), column_name, 110),'X-test') AS [MM-DD-YYYY]
from myTable;
```

Comment: According to the [`ISNULL` doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql), the result type is that of the specified column so that is why SQL Server tries to convert `x-test` to datetime when the column value is `NULL`. I suspect that is what @Zkai missed.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, no, you said "how would you expect to convert 'X-test' to a datettime". I added the documentation reference to explain **why** SQL server would try to convert 'X-test' to a datetime, which was what Zkai did not know and lead to the question.

Comment: @DanGuzman, OK I see that you like to have words from documentation instead :)